# Store SQL query string into variable BASH

Tags: sql, bash, store

I have a select statement inside a bash script that returns the latest date in the DB. I run this query 4 times so I want to define it just once and assing the text to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

    linux commands;
    database_date=$(sqlplus -s/nolog $USER/$USER@BRMDPP <<END
                 set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
                 SELECT ... 
                 exit;
END
)


    commands that change the database date;



     last_date=$(sqlplus -s/nolog $USER/$USER@BRMDPP <<END
                 set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
                 SELECT ... 
                 exit;
END
)

commands that change the database date;
```

How can I store this big string $(sqlplus ... into one variable and use it again? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make use of a function:

```
foo() {
sqlplus -s/nolog $USER/$USER@BRMDPP <<END
                 set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
                 SELECT ... 
                 exit;
END
}
```

and later invoke it by saying:

```
value=$(foo)
```

In order to get the *value* returned by the function, say `echo "$value"` (note that quoting variables is important).